# cold air return using resilient channel

Tags: walls, basement, ducts

I'm using resilient channel on a metal stud wall for sound reduction. The cold air return is in a wall that is not panned. The plan was drywall would enclose the area making it tight with airflow drawn from the room. But now, adding resilient channel will leave a 1/2” gap between stud and drywall, allowing air flow between stud and drywall and reducing draw from the room.  Should i now use panning material to enclose this area before adding resilient channel?

Comment: If you use panning you have to cut it in a way that you can bend out tabs as a boot for the grill. Sounds like work; I'd just go buy a boot. And some 3.25"x14" duct, as I'm not a fan of panning. The tabs of the boot would get attached to the channel.